# Push Messages from AWS Lambda to Kafka in another aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I want to send messages from Lambda to kafka topic which is in different aws account. My lambda is the producer.

Do we have any existing doc to setup this configuration? How Lambda is able communicate with kafka which is in another aws account?

We are using shared confluent kafka which is in different aws account and my lambda is in another aws account.

i don't see any example how to pass logins along with broker details. Do we have any example how to connect lambda to confluent kafka.

`p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'mybroker1,mybroker2'})`

it says `Failed to resolve 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.com:19092': Name or service not known`

i see following error while connecting to confluent kafka from aws lambda

```
"errorMessage": "KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str=\"Java JAAS configuration is not supported, see github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka for more information.\"}", "errorType": "KafkaException"
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/master/clients/cloud/python/producer.py

Comment: Why does the other account (or Kafka being in AWS) matter? As long as the external VPC allows for remote connections, it doesnt. E.g. The records could go over the open internet.

Comment: In other words, if you put `bootstrap.servers` as the needed address for the remote cluster, what errors are you getting?

Comment: We are using shared confluent kafka which is in different aws account and my lambda is in another aws account.

Comment: i don't see any example how to pass logins along with broker details. Do we have any example how to connect lambda to confluent kafka. 
p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'mybroker1,mybroker2'})

Comment: it says Failed to resolve 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.com:19092': Name or service not known

Comment: i see following error while connecting to confluent kafka from aws lambda please suggest on this

"errorMessage": "KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str=\"Java JAAS configuration is not supported, see https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka for more information.\"}",
  "errorType": "KafkaException",

Comment: "Name or service not known" is a DNS error and unrelated to Kafka details. The JAAS error means you've provided bad configs, and so you need to show your code. The linked example doesn't use JAAS. Also see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/python.html?utm_source=github&utm_medium=demo&utm_campaign=ch.examples_type.community_content.clients-ccloud